# ID # reference without index.html

Tags: html, navigation

long time lurker first time signup and poster.

quiet simple really

how do i reference from the navigation **page/index.html#id** to just **page#id**
- so i dont want it to show index.html

ie.
ww.page1.com/pasture#clover

i am currently using the codes below, and dont mind if i need to put in some other code. the pages will be in .php later on but for now in html.

I am using the below codes

```
<a href="pasture/#clover">Clover</a>
```

from the navigation on the first page/all pages

```
<h3 id="clover">Clover</h3>
```

and this on the target page

Comment: Does the code your currently using not work?

Comment: there's no javascript/php to support the question, which makes it unclear and too broad, but mostly unclear. Edit: to which they were removed in an edit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- There is no JS/PHP needed for Html Anchors.

Comment: or when i upload this to the server, it will automattically do this?

Comment: @Mijago well I know that; which is why I posted my comment, asking for relevance.

Comment: @glen2602 are you saying you haven't debugged first?

Comment: @evolutionxbox im saying im working in a spot at the moment where im only making this in a folder on desktop so no

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are probably right, although its very hard to convey what i was wanting to search for

Answer (score 0):

What you want: Anchors (or Bookmarks)

Look here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

So: Use `<a href="#clover">Clover</a>`

Also: If you call the site as `www.abc.de/index.html#123`, then it will stay as it is - and give you `www.abc.de/index.html#clover`.

If you call the site as `www.abc.de/#123`, then it will also stay as it is - and give you `www.abc.de/#clover`.

Edit: I misunderstood the OP. I may edit this post later. Sorry.

Comment: I think they're looking for a rewrite here.

Comment: I don't think this answers the OP's question. The anchor should lead to a different page, not the same one.

Comment: You are right - i misunderstood it.

Comment: correct, so in this instance it will be file structure of .com and lead to .com/pasture/index.html

but the link will directly pull to down to the clover section, i can get this to work with my current setup, although i want to remove the index.html